# How do I determine which parallel processing package for R to use?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am exploring parallel programming in `R` and I have a good understanding of how the `foreach` function works, but I don't understand the differences between `parallel`,`doparallel`,`doMC`,`doSNOW`,`SNOW`,`multicore`, etc.

After doing a bunch of reading it seems that these packages work differently depending on the operating system, and I see some packages use the word multicore, and others use cluster (I am not sure if those are different), but beyond that it isn't clear what advantages or disadvantages each have.

I am working Windows, and I want to calculate standard errors using replicate weights in parallel so I don't have to calculate each replicate one at a time (if I have n cores I should be able to do n replicates at once). I was able to implement it using `doSNOW`, but it looks like `plyr` and the R community in general uses `doMC` so I am wondering if using `doSNOW` is a mistake.

Regards,
Carl

Comment: I tend to use `parallel` but I don't know which is "the best"

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that `parallel` is a conglomeration of `snow` and `multicore`, and is meant to incorporate the best parts of both.

For parallel computing on a single machine, I find `parallel` to have been very effective.

For parallel computing using a cluster of multiple machines, I've never succeeded in completing the cluster set up using `parallel`, but have succeeded using `snow`.

I've never used any of the `do*` packages, so I'm afraid I'm unable to comment.

Comment: Is setting up parallel for multiple cores on a single machine the same as setting up a cluster? I want to simply use the cores on my computer, but the function I have to use is `makeCluster` so am I setting up the parallel incorrectly or am I misunderstanding the difference between cores and clusters?

Comment: A cluster is a set of cores.  So if you're using 4 cores on one computer, you have a cluster of 4 cores.  If you're using 4 cores on your local machine and 4 on a remote machine, you have a cluster of 8 cores.  `makeCluster` is just the mechanism to bind the cores together and coordinate the information going to each core.  It sounds like you're doing it right as far as I can tell.